# Ember js get a callback on a this.get() request from controller?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Hi this is probably a bit of a ember beginners question but I have been struggling with figuring out how to get a callback when making a this.get() request from a controller.

For example:

> this.get('model').then(function(){
>   //do callback stuff here
>   })

When I try and execute this in my controller I receive the error **"Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'then' "**

The reason I am trying to get a call back is I am trying to handle the loading events in the UI - for instance displaying a spinner when data is loading in

Answer (score 2):

I was trying this is on a hasMany or belongsTo property of my model.

This syntax only makes sense if the relationship property is marked async, as mine were not.

I found out thanks to @S'pht'Kr you only need the .then(…) part if there's a possibility that the related models aren't already loaded--i.e., the property really contains a DS.PromiseObject or DS.PromiseArray, i.e. it's an async relationship.

So setting the relationship properties on my model to **async:true** allowed me to get a call back on the promise with '.then()'

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting that error is because `this.get` is not returning a promise.

You could display the spinner down at the handlebars level, which I find to be the most clear approach. For example, if you are working with an array controller that will eventually fill up with some data:

```
{{#each}}
  <p>{{name}}</p>
{{else}}
  <div class="spinner">Loading content...</div>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thanks Matt for the answer